# Error: The method 'round' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: round(). Error thrown when building widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my program, I'm pulling values from cloud firestore as an initial value and want them to react on user input in case of the slider. However, the aforementioned error gets thrown. I haven't posted the entire class as it didn't let me. Just kept it to the essentials. Do let me know if you require further information. Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

````
class _ListPlusScreenState extends State<ListPlusScreen> {
  @override
  double _progress;
  
  String _name;

  Widget _BuildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    _progress = doc['Progress'];
    final _name = doc['Name'].toString();
    final _due = doc['Due'];
    final _priority = doc['Priority'];
    DocumentReference _listRef =
        Firestore.instance.collection("List Items").document();

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      width: 200,
      height: 600,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Color(0xffacb3b8),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                _name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null)
            ],
          ),
          Slider(
            value: _progress,
            min: 0.0,
            max: 100.0,
            divisions: 10,
            label: _progress.round().toString(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _progress = value;
                  _listRef.updateData({'Progress': value});
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFF6EC6CA),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('List Items').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading..');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 150,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  _BuildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

            ```
````

Comment: The error is telling you that `_progress` is null.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
double _progress =0.0;
label: _progress?.round().toString()??"0.0",
```

Change two lines of code  in your code

Comment: 'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 170 pos 15: 'value != null': is not true. 
That's the error it throws after I made the suggested changes.